# Brackets: select text string occurrences by double click

Tags: brackets

I'm currently using Brackets as IDE for JS development. I'm enjoying it, but I'm missing some features found in Sublime Text and WebStorm, like double click in some word and the editor highlights the same string occurrences in the document.

As long as I know, Brackets doesn't do that by default. Is there a plugin that adds this behavior to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Brackets an IDE? as long as I know it is just an Editor. Anyway you can use Notepad++ along with Brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found what you need. It is called **Quick Search**
Go to https://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/enturn.quick-search/enturn.quick-search-1.1.3.zip
And Install it. It is an occurance highlighter as mentioned `Automatically highlights occurrences of the selected word (like Notepad++ smart highlighting)`

Found  that from : https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/
Check for more interesting stuff!
Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

There's now an official Brackets feature for this, but you have to enable it in your preferences:

1. Choose *Debug > Open Preferences File* in the menu
2. Add a new top-level entry `"highlightMatches": true`
3. Save the file and you're done!

You can also set it to `"highlightMatches": {"showToken": true}` if you want it to highlight without even making a selection first (just based on cursor position alone).

More details are available on the preferences documentation page: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences.

Comment: This one is even better than the extension version because that one makes hard to figure what you just selected using ctrl+B (the multi selection feature). Thanks for this.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! Is there also the possibility via Brackets to highlight occurrences additional at the scroll-bar as it is implemented in the Quick Search extension?

Comment: @Chris: for that just hit Ctrl-F after double-clicking the text. You can press Esc to quickly get back out of that mode.

Comment: @ytpete: Exactly what I searched for - THX!